# Erro ao acessar o banco de dados no WebSphere

Tags: java, java-ee, ejb

Aparece esse erro depois de instalar o projeto(ele instala tudo normal e até executa e abri o projeto, mas quando vai acessar uma pagina que faz a requisição ao banco de dados da erro):

```
recoveryClasspath = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7/lib/rsadapter.rar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7/lib/rsadapter.rar;C:\WAS_LIB/db2jcc.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7/universalDriver/lib/db2jcc_license_cu.jar;C:\WAS_LIB/db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar;C:\WAS_LIB
raKey = cells/MC1373662Node01Cell/nodes/MC1373662Node01/servers/server1/resources.xml#builtin_rra
. O rastreio da pilha de exceção é: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl (initialization failure)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:140)
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.J2CUtilityClass.createMCFEntry(J2CUtilityClass.java:518)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.J2CUtilityClass.createMCFEntry(J2CUtilityClass.java:413)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.XARecoveryMgr.getMCFEntry(XARecoveryMgr.java:726)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.J2CXAResourceFactory$1.run(J2CXAResourceFactory.java:293)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.J2CXAResourceFactory.getXAResource(J2CXAResourceFactory.java:185)
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.XARecoveryData.getXARminst(XARecoveryData.java:433)
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.XARecoveryData.recover(XARecoveryData.java:559)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.PartnerLogTable.recover(PartnerLogTable.java:389)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.RecoveryManager.resync(RecoveryManager.java:1523)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.RecoveryManager.performResync(RecoveryManager.java:126)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.RecoveryManager.run(RecoveryManager.java:2200)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
```

E quando eu vou acessar a página aparece isso no log:

```
[11/02/16 15:51:34:760 GMT-03:00] 00000042 servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [EAR] [/PROJETO] [/pagina.jsp]: Inicialização bem-sucedida.
[11/02/16 15:51:34:777 GMT-03:00] 00000042 servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [EAR] [/PROJETO] [/trail.jsp]: Inicialização bem-sucedida.
[11/02/16 15:51:34:867 GMT-03:00] 00000042 lifecycle     E   JSF1054: (Phase ID: RENDER_RESPONSE 6, View ID: pagina2.jsp) Exception thrown during phase execution: javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@13921392]
[11/02/16 15:51:34:868 GMT-03:00] 00000042 servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Exceção criada não capturada em um dos métodos de serviço do servlet Faces Servlet no aplicativo S548-PROAGROEAR. Exceção criada: javax.servlet.ServletException: classe(classe2;)Ljava/util/List;
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:277)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1595)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
    at classe3$1.run(FiltroAutenticador.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:224)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:645)
    at classe4(FiltroAutenticador.java:226)
    at classe5(FiltroAutenticador.java:150)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:895)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:932)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3810)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:183)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1550)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: classe(classe;)Ljava/util/List;
    at classe(classeMB.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:131)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.faces.application.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at com.ibm.faces.renderkit.html_extended.ScriptCollectorRenderer.encodeBegin(ScriptCollectorRenderer.java:71)
    at com.ibm.faces.renderkit.DefaultAjaxRenderer.encodeBegin(DefaultAjaxRenderer.java:64)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:802)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:934)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:942)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:942)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.doRenderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:289)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:220)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
    ... 31 more

[11/02/16 15:51:34:869 GMT-03:00] 00000042 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Erro de Servlet]-[Faces Servlet]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response already committed.
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppDispatcherContext.sendError(WebAppDispatcherContext.java:602)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.sendError(SRTServletResponse.java:1179)
    at br.gov.bnb.seguranca.filtro.FiltroAutenticador.doFilter(FiltroAutenticador.java:162)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:895)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:932)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3810)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:183)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1550)

[11/02/16 15:51:34:869 GMT-03:00] 00000042 srt           W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse setStatus WARNING: Cannot set status. Response already committed.
[11/02/16 15:51:34:869 GMT-03:00] 00000042 srt           W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse addHeader WARNING: Cannot set header. Response already committed.
```

O que poderia ser, já que da ultima vez que subi o projeto tava dando tudo certo, e não lembro de ter mexido nele, desde daquele período.

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` e `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`: alguma coisa em runtime está diferente do usado para compilar, não? Reconstrua o projeto e implante novamente, veja temporários do AS e remova-os também.

Comment: Cara acho que nada está diferente e já verifiquei e não foi feita nenhuma alteração no Banco de Dados, reinstalei o projeto e nada e limpei os arquivos temporários e tbm nada. O que poderia ser?

Comment: A versão do AS é a mesma? Novamente, tem coisa diferente em *runtime*, então é só conferir como estão os classpath em *compile* e *runtime*.

Comment: Será que o erro não esta aqui? recoveryClasspath = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7/lib/rsadapter.rar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7/lib/rsadapter.rar;C:\WAS_LIB/db2jcc.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7/universalDriver/lib/db2jcc_license_cu.jar;C:\WAS_LIB/db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar;C:\WAS_LIB
raKey = cells/MC1373662Node01Cell/nodes/MC1373662Node01/servers/server1/resources.xml#builtin_rra